# ngModel binding and ngForm import issues though all code looks good. Facing many more wierd problems, any Angular version issues?

Tags: angular, ngmodel

```
ERROR in src/app/Register/register.component.html:12:9 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

12         [(ngModel)]="model.UserName"
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/Register/register.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: "./register.component.html",
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.
src/app/Register/register.component.html:3:24 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.

3   <form #registerForm="ngForm">
                         ~~~~~~

  src/app/Register/register.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: "./register.component.html",
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.
```

This error keeps coming - I have checked everything, all looks good. Tried many times. I suspect Angular version or dependency issues as I get wierd issues.  I have checked many online examples, do not see anything wrong with my code.

### Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { RegisterComponent } from "./register/register.component";
import { TasksComponent } from "./tasks/tasks.component";
import { TemplatesComponent } from "./templates/templates.component";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { MatTabsModule } from "@angular/material/tabs";
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from "@angular/material/button-toggle";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    TasksComponent,
    TemplatesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my registration module TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Registration Form</h1>
  <form #registerForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="name"
        required
        [(ngModel)]="model.UserName"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="alterEgo">Alter Ego</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alterEgo" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Registration TS file:

```
import { RegistrationModel } from "./../model/RegistrationModel";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-register",
  templateUrl: "./register.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./register.component.css"]
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  model = new RegistrationModel();
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

### Router module TS

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from "./Login/login.component";
import { RegisterComponent } from "./Register/register.component";
import { TasksComponent } from "./tasks/tasks.component";
import { TemplatesComponent } from "./templates/templates.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: "tasks", component: TasksComponent },
  { path: "templates", component: TemplatesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

RegistrationModel.ts file:

```
import { Time } from "@angular/common";

export class RegistrationModel {
  private userId: number;
  private userName: string;
  private active: boolean;
  private createTimeStamp: Time;
  private dayPhoneNumber: string;
  private eveningPhoneNumber: string;
  private cellPhoneNumber: string;
  private addressStreet: string;
  private city: string;
  private state: string;
  private country: string;
  private password: string;
  private emailAddress: string;

  get UserId() {
    return this.userId;
  }

  set UserId(value) {
    this.userId = value;
  }

  get UserName() {
    return this.userName;
  }

  set UserName(value) {
    this.userName = value;
  }

  get Active() {
    return this.active;
  }

  set Active(value) {
    this.active = value;
  }

  get CreateTimeStamp() {
    return this.createTimeStamp;
  }

  set CreateTimeStamp(value) {
    this.createTimeStamp = value;
  }

  get DayPhoneNumber() {
    return this.dayPhoneNumber;
  }

  set DayPhoneNumber(value) {
    this.dayPhoneNumber = value;
  }

  get CellPhoneNumber() {
    return this.cellPhoneNumber;
  }

  set CellPhoneNumber(value) {
    this.cellPhoneNumber = value;
  }

  get EveningPhoneNumber() {
    return this.eveningPhoneNumber;
  }

  set EveningPhoneNumber(value) {
    this.eveningPhoneNumber = value;
  }

  get AddressStreet() {
    return this.addressStreet;
  }

  set AddressStreet(value) {
    this.addressStreet = value;
  }

  get City() {
    return this.city;
  }

  set City(value) {
    this.city = value;
  }

  get State() {
    return this.state;
  }

  set State(value) {
    this.state = value;
  }

  get Country() {
    return this.country;
  }

  set Country(value) {
    this.country = value;
  }

  get EmailAddress() {
    return this.emailAddress;
  }

  set EmailAddress(value) {
    this.emailAddress = value;
  }

  get Password() {
    return this.password;
  }

  set Password(value) {
    this.password = value;
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

### Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "gui7",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to add the "ngForm" directive to your "form" tag.

```
<form ngForm #registerForm="ngForm"></form
```

There is certainly another error that will come just behind. To adjust it you will probably have to add a "name" attribute to your input.

```
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="name"
    required
    [(ngModel)]="model.UserName"
  />
```

To

```
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="name"
    name="azerty"
    required
    [(ngModel)]="model.UserName"
  />
```

Comment: The NgForm will work by itself, but the problem comes when we have a router involved.

Comment: Adding a router module is giving many errors. I spent a lot of time researching this area. I just made the router imports and other constructs directly into my app.module.ts and avoided the extra app.routing.module.ts and it now works perfectly. The examples on Angular site show that it is easy to create routes by creating a router module, but it is not so easy. It is best to use a router by using the same app.module.ts as this works easily and is also faster in compilation. Lesson learnt the hard way:Do the extra work or creating multiple modules only if your project is way too complex

Comment: Thanks JBoileau173 for the help, but I just took a short cut than solve the problem. Have a great one and stay safe.